# I am having mapper_parsing_exception when trying to elastic search to Node app with mongosastic

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, mongoose

Hey I am trying to apply elastic search to my NodeJS project but receiving following error:

```
{ Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [string] declared on field [category]

status: 400,
displayName: 'BadRequest',
message: '[mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [string] declared on field [category]',
path: '/products/_mapping/product',
query: {},
body: '{"product":{"properties":{"category":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"price":{"type":"double"},"image":{"type":"string"}}}}',
statusCode: 400,
response: '{"error":{"root_cause":[
 {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [category]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [category]"},"status":400}',
toString: [Function],
toJSON: [Function] }
```

My mapping code is following:

**product.js** file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
   category: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
       ref: 'Category'
    },
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    image: String
 });
ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
   hosts:[
       'localhost:9200'
   ]
});
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
module.exports = {
   Product
}
```

My **main.js** file

```
Product.createMapping(
{
    "mappings": {
        "products": {
            "_all": {
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                 "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
},function(err, mapping){
if(err){
    console.log('error creating mapping');
    console.log(err);
}else{
    console.log(mapping);
    console.log("mapping created");
}
});
```

**category.js**

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    }
 });
```

I don't know what is causing this error. I think it is having problem with ObjectId type of Mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch no longer supports `String` and instead has `text` or `keyword` for `String` values. You can see the post here as provided by @ryanlutgen above https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings.

To solve this issue you just have to use `es_type` while creating a model. Since it is causing error with the Category model, you should decalre it as follows

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        es_type: 'text' 
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        es_index: true
    }
 });
```

The solution is referenced from https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/436

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are attempting to specify your properties as type `string`.  Elasticsearch no longer supports `string` and instead has `text` or `keyword` for "string" values.

If you are running on version 6 of Elasticsearch, they removed backward compatibility for `string` when creating a mapping: https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: Where should I specify the type of text or keyword?

Comment: I am not familiar with the mongoosastic package, but I am assuming that they will need to update their createMapping function to convert String values in the schema to allow specification of `text` or `keyword`.  Until then, you will probably need to specify the mapping for Elasticsearch manually 
via an http/https call and see if it works.